# Which client side framework (angularjs + oauth2) to use with identityserver3

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I have done some research and found the following are the frameworks available to work with oAuth2 + AngularJs.

1. satellizer     - https://github.com/sahat/satellizer (last commit today)
2. oauth-ng       - https://github.com/angularjs-oauth/oauth-ng  (last commit 30-Jun-2016)
3. angular-oauth2 - https://github.com/oauthjs/angular-oauth2 (last commit 12-Feb-2016)
4. AngularJS-OAuth2 - https://github.com/JamesRandall/AngularJS-OAuth2 (last commit 15-Mar-2016)
5. angular-oauth  - https://github.com/angular-oauth/angular-oauth (last commit 18-Dec-2014)

Bit unclear, which one works well with ***identityserver3***. What is your recommendation ? Is there any other best frameworks available ?

Comment: How about this one: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

Comment: Brock Allen thanks for your inputs, do you recommend https://github.com/markphillips100/oidc-cordova-demo/blob/master/src/Oidc.Demo.Cordova/www/app/js/services/angular-oidc-client.js this implementation ? found from this link https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/69

Comment: Brock, any idea on https://github.com/michaelschnyder/oidc-angular, it say compatible with ids3. Do you have any recommendation on these frameworks ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the client side framework suggested by Brock Allen (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). I was able to proceed with the implementation.

Also found an interesting AngularJs Module, that was written on top of oidc-client - https://github.com/markphillips100/oidc-cordova-demo/blob/master/src/Oidc.Demo.Cordova/www/app/js/services/angular-oidc-client.js.

Comment: Do you have some snippets as to how you implemented it? As it is, the sample is coupled with cordova hybrid apps for mobile, and if you remove the cordova configuration it just loads the main page of your angular app on the login popup. I'm surely missing something.

Comment: I have implemented oidc-client-js, i was playing around with the (cordova) angular-oidc-client.js, but not done the complete implementation. I would suggest go with oidc-client-js.